# lb4 command is not found in Windows 10

Tags: npm, loopback4

I have install loopback 4 framework in my system by this command `npm i -g @loopback/cli`. But after installation by terminal I, can't create loopback application because it showing lb4 command not found. I also search through web and do many changes in environment variables but got same problem. I have executed this command with different terminal and same problem is getting.

I have attachments which will help you to understand the problem

[image]

I am running this command on command prompt in windows 10 system

Answer (score 0):

This can occur for several reasons; Typically, it's caused by a misconfigured PATH variable or a stale "cache" of the terminal. A quick solution is to use `npx @loopback/cli` instead.